# TypeError: expected str, bytes or os.PathLike object, not function

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have this task:

```
load_io_monthly_billing_to_snowflake = SnowflakeLoadOperator(
    task_id='load_io_monthly_billing_to_Snowflake',
    table=IOMonthlyBillingSnowflakeTable(),
    merge=False,
    partition=MonthlyBillingS3PartitionLatestFile(
        source_resolver=get_latest_io_monthly_billing_file_from_new_prefix,
        bucket=Variable.get('s3_bucket'),
        location_base="BTR/",
        partition_type=None
    )
)
```

in the source_resolver the operator is calling this function:

```
def get_latest_io_monthly_billing_file_from_new_prefix(*args, **kwargs):
  'does stuff to return file s3 file path'
   return file
```

and in my partition Class:

```
class MonthlyBillingS3PartitionLatestFile(Partition):
    def __init__(self,

             source_resolver,
             *args,
             obj=None,
             **kwargs):
    super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)

    self.object = obj
    self.source_resolver = source_resolver

@property
def formatted_partition_value(self):
    source = self.source_resolver
    prefix, filename = os.path.split(source)
```

This line  `prefix, filename = os.path.split(source)` is causing the error which I don't understand because the `get_latest_io_monthly_billing_file_from_new_prefix` is definitely returning a path, so why is this error happening:

```
    prefix, filename = os.path.split(source)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/posixpath.py", line 103, in split
    p = os.fspath(p)
TypeError: expected str, bytes or os.PathLike object, not function
```

Comment: `self.source_resolver` is just a reference to the `get_latest_io_monthly_billing_file_from_new_prefix` function - at no point do you actually *call* it.  Write that line as `source = self.source_resolver()`.

Comment: @jasonharper thank you so much for the explanation! I really appreciate it :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to call the function:

```
source = self.source_resolver()
```

Note the parentheses. You will also need to supply any parameters.